# Lambda Error in Nancy Sample Application

Tags: c#, rest, lambda, compiler-errors, nancy

I'm somewhat baffled by an error I am receiving while trying to get the simple Nancy example program working.

```
namespace NancyServer {

    using Nancy;

    public class ServerApi : NancyModule {
        public ServerApi() {
            Get["/"] = _ => "Hello World";
        }
    }

}
```

Visual studio 2013 pro balks at the lambda in my route.

```
_ => "Hello World";
```

I also tried a few other expressions and they all have the same problem.

```
Get["/products/{id}"] = _ => {
    System.Console.WriteLine( "test" );
};
```

The above snippet was also pulled directly from the Nancy wiki.

Intellisense underlines the lambda assignment `_ =>` and says that the delegate does not take one argument.  If I try to build I get three errors.

```
Error 1 Delegate 'System.Func<dynamic,System.Threading.CancellationToken,System.Threading.Tasks.Task<dynamic>>' does not take 1 arguments
Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<dynamic>'
Error 3 Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<dynamic,System.Threading.CancellationToken,System.Threading.Tasks.Task<dynamic>>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

I have googled for a few hours now and cannot figure out what is going on here.  Is this an environment error?  Could there be some kind of namespacing issue going on?  I have added Nancy and Nancy.Hosting.Self as dependencies to my project.  The only other code in the project is a simple main to self host the service.

```
namespace NancyServer {

    using System;
    using Nancy.Hosting.Self;

    public class ServerMain {
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            var nancyHost = new NancyHost( new Uri( "http://localhost:25000" ) );
            nancyHost.Start();
            Console.WriteLine( "Server running..." );
            Console.ReadKey();
            nancyHost.Stop();
        }
    }

}
```

I added Nancy and Nancy.Hosting.Self directly through Nuget in VS2013 pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it like so : 
`Get["/"] = (params,token) => Task.FromResult<dynamic>("Hello World");`

Nancy v2.0.0 is async all the way now.

Comment: Just to clarify, the second parameter is a `CancellationToken`

Comment: Nancy 2.0.0 is pre-release alpha, you might want to consider using the latest stable release whilst you're learning.